# jquery conflict with videobox and custom code

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

Ok I have a page that uses 3 plugins and custom code.

1. [Fullscreenr](http://designshack.net/?p=13616)
2. [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)
3. [VideoBox](http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/)

my custom code is just to change css style of items in menu(I'll post that code aswell).

My issue is that Fullscreenr and ScrollTo were working fine but when I want to add VideoBox the video popup doesn't want to work all it does is redirect to the youtube page. When I inspect the page(Chrome) it shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setProperty'
```

on this line:

```
this.overlay = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbOverlay').injectInside(document.body);
```

I have tried using $.noConflict(); Now if I removed all the other plugins then it works but that doesn't work for me cause I need everything to work.  Well hope somebody knows what I can do to fix this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/videobox.js"></script>

<!-- IF I REMOVE FROM HERE DOWN VIDEOBOX WORKS -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fullscreenr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  

    <!--
        // You need to specify the size of your background image here (could be done automatically by some PHP code)
        var FullscreenrOptions = {  width: 1024, height: 439, bgID: '#bgimg' };
        // This will activate the full screen background!
        jQuery.fn.fullscreenr(FullscreenrOptions);
    //-->
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/init.js'></script>
<script language="javascript">

    function GotoSection(divid)
    {
        $('#realBody').scrollTo( '#' + divid, 800, {duration:3000} );
        switch(divid)
        {
            case "home":
            $("#mhome").attr('class', 'selected');
            $("#mvids").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#meventos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mfotos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mcontact").attr('class', 'non');                                                                
            break;

            case "vids":
            $("#mhome").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mvids").attr('class', 'selected');
            $("#meventos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mfotos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mcontact").attr('class', 'non');                                                                
            break;

            case "eventos":
            $("#mhome").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mvids").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#meventos").attr('class', 'selected');
            $("#mfotos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mcontact").attr('class', 'non');
            break;

            case "fotos":
            $("#mhome").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mvids").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#meventos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mfotos").attr('class', 'selected');
            $("#mcontact").attr('class', 'non');
            break;

            case "contact":
            $("#mhome").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mvids").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#meventos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mfotos").attr('class', 'non');
            $("#mcontact").attr('class', 'selected');                                                       
            break;  
        }

    }


</script>
```

If there is a better script I can use I welcome any and all suggestions aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work if multiple libraries use the same $ in a webpage.

```
(function($){

//Write your jQuery code here as usual using $.

})(jQuery);
```

We define an anonymous function here, which takes jQuery as its only argument. It gets mapped to $ in the above function and your code will work just as expected. You can very well do things like this.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Write your jQuery code here as usual using $.
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: that did it! I put it at the end of my function GotoSection(divid) and moved the videobox references to after that code and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Wow Works like a Charm. Moved my jquery functions to your code and put Video box after that it works fine now . Thank you Man ...

Answer (score 0):

You must use noConflict as you are also using mootools

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/videobox.js"></script>

<!-- IF I REMOVE FROM HERE DOWN VIDEOBOX WORKS -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
  //from here you must use jQuery instead of $ or you could do

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });


</script>
```